# NameError: name 'myemailaddress' is not defined in python

Tags: python, email

sending emails with python using visual studio code

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

SenderAddress = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
password = "mypassword"

e = pd.read_excel("emails.xlsx")
emails = e['email'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(SenderAddress, password)
msg = "Hello this is a email form python"
subject = "Hello world"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, msg)
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(myemailaddress@gmail.com, email, body)
server.quit()
```

when i run the code i get the following error;

```
line 16, in <module>
   server.sendmail(myemailaddress@gmail.com, email, body)
NameError: name 'myemailaddress' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to pass the email address as a string. try: server.sendmail("myemailaddress@gmail.com",email,body)

Comment: replace `myemailaddress@gmail.com` by `SenderAddress`

Comment: server.sendmail(myemailaddress@gmail.com, email, body) try to use variable myemailaddress, quote it or use your variable server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)

Comment: [If you want to send the same message to multiple recipients, it's much better to pass them as a single list to `sendmail`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831023/send-emails-from-txt-file#comment121645011_68831023) Then the email server only keeps a single copy locally, and recipients in the same domain get copied as Bcc: recipients on the receiving end.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)` because `SenderAddress` is what's defined.  `myemailaddress@gmail.com` is a string you binded to `SenderAddress` variable.